# how to use koa router to define a default

Tags: node.js, url-routing, koa

I'm using koa-router to define routing paths

```
var app = require('koa')();
var router = require('koa-router')();

app.use(router.get('/apples', function *(next) {
}));


app.use(router.get('/oranges', function *(next) {
}));

app.use(router.routes());
app.listen(8080);
```

How do I define a route to handle everything that hasn't got a defined route? i.e. in this case, all other paths apart from /apples and /oranges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a catch-all after the routes. Unmatched requests should fall through to it.

```
router.get('/oranges', function *(next) {...});
router.get('/apples', function *(next) {...});
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(function*(next) {
  // handle unmatched...
});
```

...hope that helps.